Insert custom documentation stub for classes with PyCharm
In my code, I have a bunch of subclasses of a few main classes each of them with some specificities. I am using PyCharm Community 2024.2.3.
I would like to be able to insert a documentation stub template for each of the subclasses, so that while I am writing the documentation I have a template to follow.
In order words, I would like to be able to add something like this:
class MySubClass(MyClass):
    """
    MySubClass is a subclass of MyClass doing [insert task short description]

    Process description
    ===================

    [Enter the long process description]

    Input / Output
    ==============
    
    [DB input table]
    [DB output table]
 
    """
    pass

In this way, I will have to write only the part in the [] and I have a standard template to follow.
I have found ways to insert different documentation style stubs (rst, googledoc...), but I could not find anything to insert a customized text.
Do you have any idea?
